# Leaflet and Shiny - formal argument "selected" matched by multiple actual arguments

Tags: r, dictionary, shiny, leaflet

Folks, I almost completed my first Shiny app ever, but stumbled.
Checked all here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=shiny+map+r

My code:

```
# Packages
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)

# Set working directory
setwd("C:/My Shiny apps")

# Read csv, which was created specifically for this app
projects <- read.csv("sample data2.csv", header = TRUE) 

# Read a shapefile
countries <- readOGR(".","ne_50m_admin_0_countries")

# Merge data
projects.df <- merge(countries, projects, by.x = "name", by.y = "Country")
class(projects.df)

# Shiny code

# UI

ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Map"), 
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("countryInput", "Country",
              choices = c("a",
                          "b",
                          "c",
                          "d",
                          "e",
                          "f", 
                          "g")),
  selectInput("MFIInput", "MFI",
              choices = c("a1",
                          "b1",
                          "c1",
                          "d1",
                          "e1",
                          "f1" )),
  radioButtons("projectInput1", "Project type 1",
               choices = c("Agent banking", "mBanking", "Debit cards"),
               selected = "Agent banking"),
  radioButtons("projectInput2", "Project type 2",
               choices = c("Agent banking", "mBanking", "Debit cards"),
               selected = "mBanking"),
  radioButtons("projectStatus", "Project status",
               choices = c("Launched", "Pilot", "Planning"),
               selected = "Launched")
),
mainPanel(leafletOutput(outputId = 'map') 
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

output$map <- renderLeaflet({

pal <- colorFactor(
  palette = "Orange",
  domain = projects.df$Number, 
  reverse = FALSE)

# Create a pop-up
state_popup <- paste0("<strong>Country: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$name, 
                      "<br><strong>MFI: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$MFI,
                      "<br><strong>Number of projects: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$Number,
                      "<br><strong>Project type 1: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$Project.type.1.,
                      "<br><strong>Project type 2: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$Project.type.2.,
                      "<br><strong>Project status: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$Status)

# Create a map
projects.map <- projects.df %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(4.3419591, 19.8764526, zoom = 3) %>% 
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(projects.df$Number), 
              popup = state_popup,
              fillOpacity = 0.8, 
              color = "#BDBDC3", 
              weight = 1)

 })

 }

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This code gives me this image:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But slides and map are not linked yet:

Then I tried to add this info to server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

output$map <- renderLeaflet({

selectInput("countryInput", "Country",
            sort(unique(projects.df$Country)),
            selected = "a",
            "MFIInput", "MFI",
            sort(unique(projects.df$MFI)),
            selected = "d1",
            "projectInput1", "Project type 1",
            sort(unique(projects.df$Project.type.1.)),
            selected = "Agent network",
            "projectInput2", "Project type 2",
            sort(unique(projects.df$Project.type.2)),
            selected = "mBanking",
            "projectStatus", "Project status",
            sort(unique(projects.df$Status)),
            selected = "Launched")

pal <- colorFactor(
  palette = "Orange",
  domain = projects.df$Number, 
  reverse = FALSE)

# Create a pop-up
state_popup <- paste0("<strong>Country: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$name, 
                      "<br><strong>MFI: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$MFI,
                      "<br><strong>Number of projects: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$Number,
                      "<br><strong>Project type 1: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$Project.type.1.,
                      "<br><strong>Project type 2: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$Project.type.2.,
                      "<br><strong>Project status: </strong>", 
                      projects.df$Status)

# Create a map
projects.map <- projects.df %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(4.3419591, 19.8764526, zoom = 3) %>% 
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(projects.df$Number), 
              popup = state_popup,
              fillOpacity = 0.8, 
              color = "#BDBDC3", 
              weight = 1)

})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As a result, I have an error:
**formal argument "selected" matched by multiple actual arguments**
Map is not displayed anymore :(

Where is my mistake?
Thank you so much!

Sincerely

Oleksiy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `selectInput()`, you have several `selected =` arguments: `selected = "Senegal"`, `selected = "FINCA"` etc. which triggers the error message `formal argument "selected" matched by multiple actual arguments`.

You should have only one `selected =` argument. 
(Imagine providing a plot function with several colour for a drawing line `colour = red`, `colour = blue`...)

Comment: thanks for your answer. So, I fixed it a little bit, but I still cannot show on map multiple inputs. I can switch it now only by country, and I want to switch by every variable. For instance, now I wrote domain = input$countryInput, and I can finally switch it on map with addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(projects.df$name).